# How to parse a string into javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript object defined inside a string variable:

```
const str = "{a:1}";
```

I wonder what is the best way to convert it to a javascript object. I have searched a lot but all I found is to use `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` to convert the string. But the tricky part in this string is that it is not a JSON object. The `a` is not quoted. I have tried below approach but it doesn't parse it to a object:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str))
```

I know I can parse the string manually but I am looking for a more generic solution which support parsing all possible javascript object string.

Comment: Where does it come from? You can use a JavaScript parser to parse “all possible” JavaScript objects, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Good question Ry, how would one have Javascript code in a Javascript string in the first place?

Comment: It is from user input. I am building a mongo script interface which allows users to input the query command parameters in javascript object format as a string. But I need to convert them into javascript object

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = eval(str);
```

Just be aware that using `eval` can have performance and security impacts.

If you don't control the content of str, i.e. it is a user input or it comes from a server you don't trust, the are risks.

Also, the JavaScript runtimes optimizes your code at runtime, but often disable many optimizations when engineering an `eval`.

Try to wrap the evaluation statement in a self invoked function that receive the variable passed to the`eval`:

```
(function(s) {
    return eval(s);
}(str));
```

It ensures the creation of a closure to isolate the `eval`, mitigating it's potential impacts.

And last, don't take anything I've just said as an absolute truth: benchmark your code with and without the eval, just to be sure.

Comment: Alternatively, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval , section "Do not ever use eval!". It suggest a safer way.